# Can I annotate class of some object as type?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I want to create a

```
TDictionary<string, class of TControl>
```

that - as you can see - holds pairs of strings and references to TControl class definition to be able to call Create method on the dictionary elements at runtime.

Can I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax you need is as follows:

```
type
  TControlClass = class of TControl;
```

And then you can declare the dictionary:

```
var
  Dict: TDictionary<string, TControlClass>;
```